# api call in facebook is not working

Tags: php, facebook

Hi I m trying to create application in facebook but I m getting error as api call in facebook is not working properly. I m using following code:

```
    try {
        $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "uid: $uid<br>";
        var_dump($fbme);
        echo $e;
    }
```

In this I get uid but $fbme is NULL. The error returned is CurlException: 6: name lookup timed out.
Why this is happening??
Pls help me.

Answer (score 2):

> It is interesting to note that the PHP
>   SDK will make the old REST API call to
>   different Facebook's server based on
>   whether the API call is a
>   "READ_ONLY_CALL" or not. For
>   "READ_ONLY_CALL" requests, they will
>   be passed to "api-read.facebook.com".
>   Otherwise, the request will be passed
>   to "api.facebook.com".
>
> While I have no control on how the
>   name lookup is done on the web server
>   (as I am using web host services), **I
>   have tried to amend facebook.php by
>   renaming "api-read.facebook.com" to
>   "api.facebook.com". Well, the name
>   lookup problem is resolved.**
>
> Looking at Facebook's bug tracking
>   system reveals the fact that I am not
>   the only one who have encountered
>   this. So, you may want to apply the
>   same "workaround" if you encounter the
>   same problem.

http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/phpsdk/learning_phpsdk_07.html

Comment: Ok I tried it by replacing "api-read.facebook.com" with "api.facebook.com" in facebook.php but still I m getting $fbme as null and same error message.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem when developing locally on a virtual machine. I solved it by upping my Curl Connect Timeout.

Look for `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 10` in your facebook SDK. Try changing it to `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 30` or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 60`

Comment: This worked for me. I also changed api-read to api per @Michael

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a continuous habit of changing its API methods and call techniques. Developers face a lot of problem for this. Recently they changed their version to 3.0.0. But for the above code, there is some error with your coding technique. You can match your code with [this one](http://wizardsoweb.com/simple-facebook-graph-api-iframe-application-full-code/2011/05/) and see what is wrong. as i have left Facebook programming, i can directly help you in the code. sorry.